# Usage of Nuxt3 and Tippy.js delegation not working

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, tippyjs

Tip delegation doesn't do anything with an SSR app using Nuxt3, even with elements available at load time and dynamic elements.

app.vue

```
<div id="tippyRoot">
   <NuxtPage/>
</div
```

sample element

```
<a
     data-tippy-content="Learn More About Schema.org"
     href="https://schema.org/"
     target="_blank"
     >Schema.org</a>
```

tippy init (have tried to init at app.vue and as a store action both on onMounted and even with setTimeout)

```
delegate("#tippyRoot", {
        target: "[data-tippy-content]",
        content: 'loading',
        animation: "scale",
        trigger:'hover',
        onShown(instance) {
          instance.setContent(instance.reference.dataset.tippyContent);
        },
 });
```

All elements have the appropriate data attribute but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Other tips targeting specific elements using tippy() work but when I wanna target multiple static and dynamic elements using delegate() or tippy() it doesn't work.  No errors at all, hard to debug...Been using this library for a long time but after switching to SSR it's been tough to get it work.

Comment: seems like the trigger is not valid: hover => mouseenter, but it was hard to debug as there was no warning. Also had to change onShown => onShow. Will wait for a conclusive answer on the developers repo but this seems to fix the issue.